# One sided matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the matrix $A \in K^{m \times n}$, then there exists a matrix $B \in K^{n \times m}$ with $AB = I_m$ if the **rows** of $A$ are linearly independent.

Similarly there is a matrix $B \in K^{n \times m}$ with $BA = I_n$ if the **columns** of $A$ are linearly independent.

How can I go about proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then upon row-reduction we find that every column of $A$ is a pivot-column.  In other words, there exists an invertible matrix $R$ (encoding our row-operations) such that 
$$
RA = \pmatrix{I_{n \times n}\\0_{(m-n)\times n}}.
$$
Now, break the matrix $R$ into blocks. Using block-matrix multiplication, we have
$$
\pmatrix{I_{n \times n}\\0_{(m-n)\times n}} = RA = \pmatrix{R_1\\R_2}A = \pmatrix{R_1 A\\ R_2 A}.
$$
So, we have $R_1A = I_{n \times n}$.  So, taking $B = R_1$ gives us a matrix $B$ such that $BA = I$.

If $A$ has linearly independent rows, then $A^T$ has linearly independent columns. If we pick a matrix $C$ such that $C A^T = I$, then we find that
$$
CA^T = I \implies (CA^T)^T = I^T \implies A C^T = I.
$$
So, $B = C^T$ is a matrix for which $AB = I$.

---

An alternative version of the second proof: in this case, we have $m \leq n$.

Suppose that $A$ has linearly independent rows. This is equivalent to the statement that the row-reduced form $RA$ of $A$ has no row of zeros.

Now, let $e_i$ denote the $i$th row of the $m \times m$ identity matrix.  Note that $Me_i$ gives you the $i$th column of $M$.  So, suppose $i_1,\dots,i_m$ are the numbers corresponding to the pivot columns of $RA$.  Build the matrix $P$ out of the columns $e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_m}$.  We find that
$$
(RA)P = I
$$
We see then that $AP$ is an invertible matrix, and $R$ is the inverse of $AP$.  It follows that we also have 
$$
APR = I.
$$
So, taking $B = PR$ gives us a matrix for which $AB = I$, as desired.

Comment: Isn't possible to do what you did in the second part of your proof in the first part as well ?

Comment: If I really wanted to use the same proof, I would have to use column-operation instead of row-operations.  Yes, though, it is possible; I prefer my way though because it's quicker to write.  I don't see a way to tackle the independent-rows proof using row-reduction, though.

Comment: I see what you mean. Is it there a way to write your proof without "block-matrix multiplication" using what was written in the previous answer?

Comment: Sure, just look at the product $RA$ one row at a time.  By doing this, you can see that if we build a matrix $B$ out of the first $n$ rows of $R$, then each row of $BA$ will be a row of the identity matrix so that all together, $BA = I$.

Comment: This all uses the fact that if $r_1,\dots,r_m$ are the $1 \times n$ rows of $R$, then the $i$th row of $RA$ is given by $r_i A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me understand.

Comment: @V1C10USG4M3R I've come up with an alternative proof for the second case, if you're interested.  This lines up nicely with Robert's proof.  In particular, $(AP)$ is an invertible matrix that can be built by taking "some $m$ columns of $A$".

Comment: Thank you for that as well :D

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, $A$ has rank $m$, and we must have $m \le n$.  Then some $m$ columns of $A$ form an invertible matrix.  The corresponding rows of $B$ can be the inverse of this matrix, and any other rows are $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped me a lot. :D